# Advice to calculate the transfer function of circuits

Tags: operational-amplifier, transfer-function, cascode

I'm a bit confused, to get the transfer function, what's the approach to work out in the cascade arranges like these?

[image]

I know it should be done using superposition, but passing R2 and cR3 I got lost and can't land a KCL equation that makes sense.

I'm only asking for the technique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: -

Just use your eyes and simplify. Here's a big start: -

[image]

Now it's your turn - take this diagram and simplify each stage to just its gain values.

No need to use KCL if you understand how op-amps work.

Comment: Thanks sometimes is hard to see it (to me), sorry to bother, do you have a book or site where can I find more problem like these to  level up the  work out ?

Comment: @avelardo I haven't read a book on electronics in decades. Sorry

Comment: dont mind, Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Andyaka  After 359k  reputation points, I'd say you've WRITTEN a couple electronics books by now!!!

Answer (score 1):

I break it down into **6 blocks** or **stages** if you wish:

- 3 inverting amplifiers
- one unity-gain buffer
- one difference amplifier
- one resistor voltage divider

(not in any order).
Sharp-eyed @Andyaka has spotted  two sequential amplifiers that do essentially nothing: transfer function is +1.0 from input of one amplifier to output of 2nd amplifier.

I note that each of 5 blocks are independent of others - meaning that an individual block's transfer function isn't changed by preceding or following blocks. Their independence makes combining the transfer function of each block an easy affair. These blocks have one input and one output.

The difference amplifier has two inputs, so this block has an output that is more complex (depending on TWO inputs).

---

An opinion:
To instructors/professors: what a waste of opamps!
 If you're going to ask students to analyze circuits, give them circuits they might see real-world. Op's circuit is mostly nonsense.

Comment: some friends has been trying to tell it , but he simple dosnt care, but even so I think is a good proffessor.

Comment: @avelardo I know some (good) instructors who offer complex problems. You can solve with long, complex, tedious math - wasting your time. Or you can recognize a simplification, or apply a "rule" that provides a quick path to solution. Watch for those.